# Using variables outside of an if-statement

Tags: java, if-statement, scope

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible in Java, but how would I use a string declared in an if-statement outside of the if-statement it was declared in?

Comment: Declare the string before the `if`? Need some code to clarify what you are asking!

Comment: You can't unless you assign it to a variable declared outside the variable. Maybe you can post a part of your code you're having trouble with and we can help you with that.

Answer (score 21):

You can't because of [variable scope](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm).

If you define the variable inside an `if` statement, than it'll only be visible inside the scope of the `if` statement, which includes the statement itself plus child statements.

```
if(...){
   String a = "ok";
   // a is visible inside this scope, for instance
   if(a.contains("xyz")){
      a = "foo";
   }
}
```

You should define the variable outside the scope and then update its value inside the `if` statement.

```
String a = "ok";
if(...){
    a = "foo";
}
```

Comment: That would work, but I need to use the strings the way they were defined in the if statement outside of the if statement... If that makes any sense.

Comment: Initialize them with some default value, like null, update them in the if block and then when using them outside the block they'll have the correct value; you can also check if their value remains the default.

Answer (score 8):

You need to distinguish between a variable *declaration* and *assignment*.

```
String foo;                     // declaration of the variable "foo"
foo = "something";              // variable assignment

String bar = "something else";  // declaration + assignment on the same line
```

If you try to use a declared variable without assigned value, like :

```
String foo;

if ("something".equals(foo)) {...}
```

you will get a compilation error as the variable is not assigned anything, as it is only declared.

In your case, you declare the variable inside a conditional block

```
if (someCondition) {
   String foo;
   foo = "foo";
}

if (foo.equals("something")) { ... }
```

so it is only "visible" inside that block. You need to move that declaration *outside* and assign it a value somehow, or else you will get conditional assignment compilation error. One example would be to use an `else` block :

```
String foo;

if (someCondition) { 
   foo = "foo";
} else {
   foo = null;
}
```

or assign a default value (null?) on declaration

```
String foo = null;

if (someCondition) {
   foo = "foo";
}
```