# Why can't I call new polygon?

Tags: java

My teacher gave me this

1. In a n - sided regular polygon, all sides have the same length and all angles have the same degree. Design a class named RegularPolygon that contains:
   A private int data field named n that defines the number of sides in the Polygon with default value 3.
   A private double data field named side that stores the length of the side with default value 1.
   A private double data field named X that defines the x - coordinate of the polygon’s center with default value 0.
   A private double data field named Y that defines the y - coordinate of the polygon’s center with default value 0.
   A constructor that creates a regular polygon with the specified number of sides, length of side, and x - and y- coordinates (values are passed from the parameters to the fields).
   The accessor methods for all data fields.
   The method getPerimeter() that returns the perimeter of the polygon.
   The method getArea() that returns the area of the polygon. The formula is Area = n * s*s / (4 * tan(PI / n)).

2) Write a RegularPolygonTest class, allow the user to enter the data fields, and your program prints out the perimeter and the area of the regular polygon.

This is my code so far:

```
public class RegularPolygon{
    private int n;
    private double side, x, y;
    public RegularPolygon(){
        n = 3;
        side = 1;
        x = 0; 
        y = 0;
    }

    public RegularPolygon(int n, double side){
        this.n = n;
        this.side = side;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    public RegularPolygon(int sn, double length, double x_coord, double y_coord){
        n = sn;
        side = length;
        x = x_coord;
        y = y_coord;
    }

    //set n to the user input
    public void setN(int other){
            n = other;
    }
    public int getN(){
        return n;
    }
    //set side to userinput
    public void setSide(double otherside){
        side = otherside;
    }
    public double getSide(){
        return side;
    }
    //set x to user input
    public void setX(int x_co){
        x = x_co;
    }
    public double getX(){
        return x;
    }
    //set y to user input
    public void setY(int they){
        y = they;
    }
    public double getY(){
        return y;
    }
//find perimeter
    public double getPerimeter(){
        return n * side;
    }
//find area
    public double getArea(){
        double s_squ = side * side;
        double pin = Math.PI/n;
        double tangent = Math.tan(pin);
        return (n*s_squ)/(4*tangent);
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RegularPolygonTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner yer = new Scanner(System.in);
        //number of sides
        System.out.println("Enter number of sides: ");
        int sn = yer.nextInt();

        //length of sides
        System.out.println("Enter length of sides: ");
        double length = yer.nextDouble();

        //x-coord
        System.out.println("Enter the x-coordinate of the center: ");
        double x_coord = yer.nextDouble();

        //y-coord
        System.out.println("Enter the y-coordinate of the center: ");
        double y_coord = yer.nextDouble();

        if (x_coord == 0 && y_coord == 0){
            RegularPolygon rp = new RegularPolygon(sn, length);
        }
        else if (sn > 3 && length > 1){
            RegularPolygon rp = new RegularPolygon(sn, length, x_coord, y_coord); 

        }
        else{
            RegularPolygon rp = new RegularPolygon();
        }
        System.out.println("The perimeter of the " + rp.getN() + "-sided polygon is : "+ rp.getPerimeter() +". And the are is : "+ rp.getArea());
    }

}
```

The error I get is that the IDE can't find symbol and it points to all of the rp in the last line. How might I fix this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using variables outside of an if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337529/using-variables-outside-of-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 2):

All the rp are inside blocks. You need to define a possibly uninitialized rp before the ifs and use this common rp within the ifs.