# How can I call on a variable initialized from within an if statement?

Tags: java

For context I'm a first year It student. We are tasked to create a concept program for a payment system for our final project. We decided to do a payroll program.
Here is a snippet of my code using JOptionFrame and JOptionPane

```
//Wages based on Job Position
    if (JobPositionComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Project Manager")){
        double wage = 350.f;
        jTextArea1.append("Total Salary this month : " + df.format(hour * wage) + "\n");
    }
    else if (JobPositionComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("System Analyst")){
        double wage = 250.f;
        jTextArea1.append("Total Salary this month : " + df.format(hour * wage) + "\n");
    }
    else if (JobPositionComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("System Developer")){
        double wage = 320.f;
        jTextArea1.append("Total Salary this month : " + df.format(hour * wage) + "\n");
    }
    else if (JobPositionComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Quality Assurance")){
        double wage = 220.f;
        jTextArea1.append("Total Salary this month : " + df.format(hour * wage) + "\n");
        
    
    } 
    jTextArea1.append("Payment Option : " + PaymentOptionComboBox.getSelectedItem() + "\n");
    jTextArea1.append("--------------------------------------------");
    
    
    //Payment option information prompts
    if (PaymentOptionComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Bank Account")){
       
    String ban = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your Bank Account Number", "Payment Option",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
     int BAN = Integer.parseInt(ban);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Transaction Information : " +
                "\nName : " + NameTextField.getText()  +
                "\nBank Account Number : " + BAN +        //I can't call on the wage inside the if statements, it just shows an error.
                "\nPayment Amount : " + df.format(hour * wage) +
                "\nPlease Confirm your information","Bank Account", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        ImageIcon BDO = new ImageIcon(SystemFrame.class.getResource("BDO.png"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Transaction Complete" + 
                "\nThank you for choosing our bank","Bank Account",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,BDO); 
}
```

Since the number assigned to the wage variable is dependent on the job position, I have to call it from within the if statements for the computation to be accurate. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: You want to access the initialized `wage` variable outside the `if` block?

Comment: Declare it once before all the `if` statements, then just use assignments (and not a declaration) within the `if` block.

Comment: [This answer for "Using variables outside of an if-statement" might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13337578/6073886)

Comment: @f1sh considering the fact that OP is a 1st year student, I posted the answer with implemented code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below and see if it works.

```
double wage; //declaring outside if block as a class variable/member

//Wages based on Job Position
if (JobPositionComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Project Manager")){
        wage = 350.f;
        jTextArea1.append("Total Salary this month : " + df.format(hour * wage) + "\n");
    }
    else if (JobPositionComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("System Analyst")){
        wage = 250.f;
        jTextArea1.append("Total Salary this month : " + df.format(hour * wage) + "\n");
    }
    else if (JobPositionComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("System Developer")){
        wage = 320.f;
        jTextArea1.append("Total Salary this month : " + df.format(hour * wage) + "\n");
    }
    else if (JobPositionComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Quality Assurance")){
        wage = 220.f;
        jTextArea1.append("Total Salary this month : " + df.format(hour * wage) + "\n");
        
    
    } 
    jTextArea1.append("Payment Option : " + PaymentOptionComboBox.getSelectedItem() + "\n");
    jTextArea1.append("--------------------------------------------");
    
    
    //Payment option information prompts
    if (PaymentOptionComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Bank Account")){
       
    String ban = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your Bank Account Number", "Payment Option",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
     int BAN = Integer.parseInt(ban);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Transaction Information : " +
                "\nName : " + NameTextField.getText()  +
                "\nBank Account Number : " + BAN +        //I can't call on the wage inside the if statements, it just shows an error.
                "\nPayment Amount : " + df.format(hour * wage) +
                "\nPlease Confirm your information","Bank Account", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        ImageIcon BDO = new ImageIcon(SystemFrame.class.getResource("BDO.png"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Transaction Complete" + 
                "\nThank you for choosing our bank","Bank Account",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,BDO); 
}
```

The problem with your existing code is `variable scoping`. You are trying to access the variable outside it's scope. Hence the error. You can read more about it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope) or [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/)

Comment: Solved! I just have to assign the wage declaration outside the if statement with a number for it to work. Thank you!